# Count number of times LOC has executed in **PROD** - for java app

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, instrumentation, lines-of-code

I am working on a distributed application with 50 different modules. These have very less test coverage. Clearly,I need to prioritize which modules/classes needs testing. Is there a way to understand how many times a given line of code has been executed in prod (and, which class is used at what frequency by real time production usage pattern) for say a week ? I mention prod as this instrumentation should not affect the already running code due to obvious sensitive reasons. We use maven for deployment. I heard, corbetura can come in handy for this use case-but,could not find how from their documentation. Any one did a similar thing before ? Note that assumption is there are no unit test cases in the already running code at production.

Comment: https://github.com/danmayer/coverband looks roughly like what you're after but it's unfortunately ruby.

Answer (score 0):

We use [newrelic](http://www.newrelic.com)
[image: Highest throughput transactions]

It will let you know which method is used the most, which is the slowest one, db performance and more.
That's how we monitor production and we also used it to plan our stress tests.

I hope that helps.

Comment: thanks. not able to vote up. but, i will try this and set this as answer - looks promising

Comment: @gov you should look into [newrelic insights](http://newrelic.com/insights) using this feature you can query in realtime to distinguish which service/module is responding slower or have a higher rate of exceptions.